# How to skip a blank cell and while concatenating in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

My cell values read as follows:

```
Column A1  Column B1   Column C1   Column D1  Column E1  Column F1
Blank      Text 1      Text 2      Blank      Text 3     Concatenate Col A to E
```

While concatenating this, I expect the values as below:

```
Column F1
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
```

I use the formula below and I get:

```
=A1&CHAR(10)&B1&CHAR(10)&C1&CHAR(10)&D1&CHAR(10)&E1

Blank
Text 1
Text 2
Blank
Text 3
```

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can test the length of each cell before including it in your formula's results. Something like this:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>0,A1&CHAR(10),"")&IF(LEN(B1)>0,B1&CHAR(10),"")&IF(LEN(C1)>0,C1&CHAR(10),"")&IF(LEN(D1)>0,D1&CHAR(10),"")&IF(LEN(E1)>0,E1,"")
```

This checks that each cell has a length greater than 0 before including it.

To break it down, the formula is 4 identical constructions and 1 similar construction. There are 4 of these:

```
IF(LEN([cell])>0,[cell]&CHAR(10),"")
```

which says: If the length of [cell] is greater than 0, then use the value of the cell and CHAR(10). If it is not greater than 0, then use an empty string ("").

The last section is the same thing, but without including the CHAR(10):

```
IF(LEN([cell]>0,[cell],"")
```

It might be easiest to see the full formula's construction in the following form:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>0,A1&CHAR(10),"")
&IF(LEN(B1)>0,B1&CHAR(10),"")
&IF(LEN(C1)>0,C1&CHAR(10),"")
&IF(LEN(D1)>0,D1&CHAR(10),"")
&IF(LEN(E1)>0,E1,"")
```